# Toggle is-active css classes on navigation tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm pretty new to Vue so I'm building a test project to try it out. I have some tabs:

```
<div class="tabs">
      <ul>
           <li class="is-active"><a> first tab </a></li>
           <li><a> second tab </a></li>
           <li><a> third tab</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

now, using Vue I want to have a method that removes the `is-active` class from all `li`s and set `is-active` to the `li` clicked.

I've dabbled a bit but I can't find any straightforward ways to go about it. I see that Vue has good solutions for conditional rendering but I need to fix this part first.

Where should I be looking, and how are problems like these usually solved in Vue? Do you just loop through all children of `ul` to remove the class, then set `is-active` based on the index of the `li`?

Answer (score 10):

There are a dozen ways you can do this.

Here is a quick one.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    activeTab: 1
  }
})
```

```css
.is-active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li :class="{'is-active': activeTab === 1}" @click="activeTab = 1"><a> first tab </a></li>
      <li :class="{'is-active': activeTab === 2}" @click="activeTab = 2"><a> second tab </a></li>
      <li :class="{'is-active': activeTab === 3}" @click="activeTab = 3"><a> third tab</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue is data driven. You typically want to drive the HTML based on data. Here, `class` is driven by the `activeTab`, and `activeTab` is set by clicking list elements.

At some point, your tabs are likely to be data instead of hardcoded. Then your code ends up looking something like this.

```js
console.clear()

const tabs = [{text: "first tab"}, {text: "second tab"}, {text: "third tab"}]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    activeTab: tabs[0],
    tabs
  }
})
```

```css
.is-active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="tab in tabs"
          :class="{'is-active': activeTab === tab}"
          @click="activeTab = tab">
        <a>{{tab.text}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And so forth. This is how this kind of thing is accomplished with Vue.

Comment: Maybe you can help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566362/how-can-i-add-button-selected-if-clicked-on-the-box-list